# How does someone debug Sails.js code in Visual Studio?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, sails.js, node.js-tools

I'm currently trying out Node.JS and using [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) with [Node.js Tools](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/) as my primary IDE.

If I would create an Express application using this interface:
[image]

Then I would hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, my Express application would start and I'd see this nice debug window:

[image]

However, if I install [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) using `npm -g install sails`, I no longer see this debug window in my test Sail.js app (if I create one in my Visual Studio), nor in Express app.

My application would start as expected, except that I can't see debug window anymore.

Debug window comes back only if I do following:

1. Remove Sails from my machine using `npm -g uninstall sails`
2. Reinstall node.js

How do I get debug window if I have Sails installed? I'd like to have it for both Express and Sails applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ran into a similar issue of running Sails application inside Visual Studio. Here's how I got my project properly running in Visual Studio, in case any stumbles on that question.

1. Create **Create Blank Node.JS Console Application** in the VS
2. In *another folder outside of your project* initialize your sails app (if you haven't already), e.g. sails create appName. If you already know your API controllers/models, it's a good idea to create them right now. If not, you'll have to do it manually rather than using **sails generate api**
3. **IMPORTANT:** In Sails project folder, remove node_modules, in my case existing node modules were throwing VS npm off the track
4. In the visual studio, right click on your project, go to *Add* > *Add Existing Folder...*
5. Select your folder with Sails Application
6. Once it's imported, you'll notice that you have a folder with sails application that also has app.js. Select all the contents of sails project and move them a level up to your root. It should replace *app.js, package.json & readme*.
7. Right click on *npm*, select *Install missing packages...*
8. After that, right click on you app.js file and select it as start js file
9. Run/Debug the application. It should work just fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Been a while I used sails with visual studio, but I'll mark it as accepted to take the credits for investigation :)

Comment: Yeah, I switched to using a lighter framework instead of sails since our project doesn't need as much overhead, but I hope it'll help someone who does run with sails :)